# Auto-submit a radio button but keep it selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I am using radio buttons to sort through paginated results. However, whenever the button is clicked and auto-submitted, it becomes unselected. I want to keep the button selected so that the user knows which one they selected. How can I do that?

Here is what I have:

```
function autoSubmit() {
    var formObject = document.forms['theForm'];
    formObject.submit();
}

<input type="radio" name="sort" value="time" onChange="autoSubmit();" />
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="year" onChange="autoSubmit();" />
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="name" onChange="autoSubmit();" />

if(isset($_GET["sort"])) { 
    $sort = $_GET["sort"];
}
```

Comment: If you want to submit your form each time the user change something, you might like to use an ajax solution, so the page won't reload each time (it will give a better user experience).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume that your code is something like this:

```
<?php
$sort = "";
if(isset($_GET["sort"]))
{ $sort = $_GET["sort"]; }
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function autoSubmit()
{
    var formObject = document.forms['theForm'];
    formObject.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='theForm' id='theForm'>
    <input type="radio" name="sort" <?php if ($sort == 'upload_time') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?>value="upload_time" onChange="autoSubmit();" />Recently Uploaded
    <input type="radio" name="sort" <?php if ($sort == 'article') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> value="article" onChange="autoSubmit();" /> Alphabetically
    <input type="radio" name="sort" <?php if ($sort == 'year') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> value="year" onChange="autoSubmit();" /> Most Recent
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 - better answer than mine since I don't know php very well.  :)  This is what I had in mind!

Comment: I would not send a answer cause your answer is right! But I just wanted to give a more complete answer.

Comment: btw, thank you for vote-up. now I can comment on other answers. I've been waiting for that!! hahaha =)

Answer (score 1):

Do this server-side.  Set the attribute `checked="checked"` in the radio button that is selected.