# Re - Autosubmit radio but keep it selected

Tags: php, html

Here is a link to the above subject, the code of which I have used:

[Auto-submit a radio button but keep it selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351725/auto-submit-a-radio-button-but-keep-it-selected)

The code I want to use is similar to :

```
<?php if ($order_disc == 'A) { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?>
```

but I have to amend it because it is in a class. I am sending my html as a string

```
$Chk = '
<script type="text/javascript">
function autoSubmit()
{
    document.getElementById("discount").submit();
}
</script>
<div id="theOverlay">&nbsp; 
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
     <tr>
         <td width="200"">
         <input type="radio" name="order_disc"  checked="checked" '. if ($order_disc == "S") { . 'checked="checked" '. ;  } . '
         value="S"  onChange="autoSubmit();" />Stock <br/> 
         <input type="radio" name="order_disc" 
          value="V" onChange="autoSubmit();" /> VOR <br/>
```

but as this is a string I had to change all the `<?php` to `'.` and all the `?>` to `.'`

These single quotes fail on being parsed and I get a syntax error. Is there a way around this?

Comment: thanks for moving the code in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
$Chk = '
<script type="text/javascript">
function autoSubmit()
{
    document.getElementById("discount").submit();
}
</script>
<div id="theOverlay">&nbsp; 
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
     <tr>
         <td width="200"">
         <input type="radio" name="order_disc" ';
     if ($order_disc == "S") { $Chk.= 'checked="checked" ';  }
     $Chk .= 'value="S"  onChange="autoSubmit();" />Stock <br/> 
         <input type="radio" name="order_disc" 
          value="V" onChange="autoSubmit();" /> VOR <br/>
```