# Is it possible to send the data of a form to the server when I select them?

Tags: html, ajax, forms

```
<div class="modal-body modal-body-step-2">
    <form action="prenotazioni.php" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="spettacolo" value="Lo Schiaccianoci">Lo Schiaccianoci<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spettacolo" value="Cavalleria Rusticana">Cavalleria Rusticana<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spettacolo" value="Don Quijote">Don Quijote<br>
            <input type="radio" name="spettacolo" value="La Bohème">La Bohème<br>
        </div>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" name="inserisci" value="Controlla gli orari disponibili">
</div>

<div class="modal-body modal-body-step-3">
    <form action="prenotazioni2.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="spettacolo" value="<?php echo $_POST['spettacolo'];?>" readonly>
        .........
    </form>
</div>
```

Is it possible to send the data of a form to the server when I select them?
In step 3 I can't see the show I selected.
I read on the web that I have to use ajax but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Kindly explain your question more and also refer to this [ask].

Comment: You are probably looking for AJAX; a web search should find a lot of tutorials for various languages and server backends.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to autosend the radiobutton values right? If so, refer to *onChange* and provide it with a JS function. [Similar problematic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351725/auto-submit-a-radio-button-but-keep-it-selected)

Comment: I tried to adapt this to my code but it doesn't work. I'm not a javascript expert.